# Changing DataTable from react-data-table-component pagination buttons color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, react-table, handle

I want the pagination buttons to change their color when it's dark theme to be white and when it's light theme to be black, this is how I coded but I don't know how to change.

```
          <DataTable
                columns={columns.map((element) => {
                  return {
                    name: element.name.toUpperCase(),
                    selector: element.selector,
                    sortable: element.sortable,
                  };
                })}
                data={rowsList}
                pagination={pagination}
                defaultSortField={defaultSortField}
                selectableRows={selectableRows}
                highlightOnHover={highlightOnHover}
                onRowClicked={onRowClicked}
                customStyles={{
                  headCells: {
                    style: {
                      background: "var(--secondary-color)",
                      color: "var(--text-color)",
                    },
                  },
                  cells: {
                    style: {
                      background: "var(--secondary-color)",
                      color: "var(--text-color)",
                    },
                  },
                  pagination: {
                    style: {`your text`
                      background: "var(--secondary-color)",
                      color: "var(--text-color)",
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
```